# Pointer being free was not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently testing a linked list that I'm building and when I run the code below I get a "pointer being free was not allocated" I know that this is to do with the delete_queue function but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "smb.h"

#define BUFLEN (25)

struct Queue {
  stage *front, *back;
};

typedef struct Queue * Queue;

Queue queue_create(void) {
  Queue q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
  q->front = q->back = NULL;
  return q;
}

void queue_delete(Queue q) {
  stage *current, *tmp;
  current = q->front;
  while (current!= NULL) {
    tmp = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = tmp;
  }


  free(q);
}

void queue_push(Queue q, char * name, int ncoins, int npipes) {
  stage *n =malloc(sizeof(struct stage));
  strcpy(n->name, name);
  n->ncoins = ncoins;
  n->npipes = npipes;
  n->next = NULL;
  stage *current;

  if (q->front == NULL) {
    q->front = n;
  } else {


    current = q->front;
    while(current!= NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = n;

  }
  q->back = n;
  q->back->next = q->front;
}



int main(void) {
    Queue q = queue_create();
    queue_push(q, "courtyard", 1, 2);

    int data1 = q->front->ncoins;
    int data2 = q->front->npipes;








    printf("%d\n", data1);
    printf("%d\n", data2);
    printf("%s\n", q->front->name);



    queue_delete(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should we assume `q->back->next = q->front` is not a mistake and you are *intentionally* forming a **circular linked list**? If so, clearly checking for NULL on such a list when non-empty as a termination condition isn't going to work. Your deletion code eventually ends up deleting nodes that are already deleted, and your push-code will enter into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 while(current->next!=NULL)
```

as opposed to this

```
 while(current!=NULL)
```

when you get to the last node you are calling tmp->next which is past the last node. so your pointer is pointing to the middle of nowhere.

Comment: Wouldn't `tmp` and `current` just both end up as `NULL` in the original code, with no problem? If `current->next` is `NULL`, we set `tmp` to it, we free `current`, we set `current` to `NULL`, we stop. I see no problem there.

Comment: If your next node is initialized as NULL when creating new nodes then it shouldn't be a problem, but if it is not then when you point to next it will not point to NULL and instead will be pointing to a random spot in memory.

Comment: Oh wait, hold on, there are two lines containing `while (current != NULL)`, which one are you talking about?

Comment: The one in delete_queue.  Hold on actually, try something like this
'while(q->front!=NULL){'
'current=q->front->next;'
'free(q->front);'
'q->front=current;'

Comment: @Dukeling *neither* will work correctly. The list as presented is circular on the first node insertion, which finishes with `q->back->next = q->front;`. There are no NULL `next` pointers in the list at that point. There is a single node that self-references (points to itself). And it is noteworthy that if `push` were called again at that point an infinite loop would ensue.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't notice that in the push function.

Comment: @SudoAndrew It is ultimately the root of the problem, and unless the intent is to have a circular list, it shouldn't be there in the first place. If the intent is circular, both the insertion logic an the cleanup logic need significant attention.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you so much for making me realise that. Yes, the intent is to have a circular linked list. Any thoughts on how I could improve the insertion?

Comment: @Dukeling Well I would say if you want a linked list that is circular you should probably declare it in the constructor.  So have it something like. q->front->next = q->back; q->back->previous = q->front;  then in your queue_delete would be something like while(current->next!= q->back){  tmp = current->next; free(current);  current = tmp; } something like that would probably work for the delete.

Comment: @SudoAndrew the problem is that I am not allowed to modify the header file for my node, it doesn't have a pointer to previous